# Jquery .each won't loop scrollheight values

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to set the height of every textarea to the proper size to avoid scroll bars.  The textarea's come dynamically through an ajax post (response html).

I've tried for and searched for hours to make this work.  However, it will only ever return the first textarea scrollheight (can only resize the first textarea to fit data) . I can get the .each to return and modify any other data like id's or text found in each textarea, but it only ever returns the very first scrollHeight value.

```
$('textarea').each(function() {
$(this).height($(this).prop('scrollHeight'));
                     });
```

I've also tried changing them $('textarea')[0].scrollHeight; also tried the same using the index as a parameter in the function(index) ... $('textarea')[index].scrollHeight;

Stack answers have not been helpful.

ATTN: Solved. Noob mistake.  I initially set the div the textarea was in to display: none;  Since the parent didn't take up space, neither did the child textarea.  So when I got the scrollHeight it was returning 0;

Comment: do you mean each time the function fires, you get the scrollHeight of the first textarea, or is it that only the first one shows a correct value and the other times it fails to get the scrollHeight?

Answer (score -1):

Each method signature is .each(array, callback(i,val){})
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: Try again: http://api.jquery.com/each/  (protip: there's two different 'each' methods in jquery)

Answer (score -1):

`scrollHeight` is a javascript attribute of elements not a html property. You need to use `this.scrollHeight` I suppose.